# App crashing with simple XML layout

Tags: android

I Make An App "Birthday card" That Contains a Image View and two Text Views And I Run this on Genymotion Emulator And The Message Appear

> "Unfortunately,Happy Birthday has stopped."

1-ActivityMain.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/androidparty" />


    <TextView
        android:text="Happy Birthday Mohamed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
        android:text="From,Abo Elmagd"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

2- MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.happybirthday;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

}

3- logcat

```
02-17 21:31:57.757 1658-1658/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
02-17 21:31:57.869 1658-1658/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method 
android.view.Window$Callback.onPointerCaptureChanged, referenced from method 
android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPointerCaptureChanged
02-17 21:31:57.869 1658-1658/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface 
method 15988: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onPointerCaptureChanged (Z)V
02-17 21:31:57.869 1658-1658/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 
0x0002
02-17 21:31:57.869 1658-1658/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method 
android.view.Window$Callback.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts, referenced from 
method 
android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts
02-17 21:31:57.869 1658-1658/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface 
method 15990: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts 
(Ljava/util/List;Landroid/view/Menu;I)V
02-17 21:31:57.873 1658-1658/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 
0x0002
02-17 21:31:57.873 1658-1658/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class 
referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
02-17 21:31:57.873 1658-1658/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method 
android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method 
android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
02-17 21:31:57.873 1658-1658/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface 
method 15992: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested 
(Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
02-17 21:31:57.873 1658-1658/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 
0x0002
02-17 21:31:57.877 1658-1658/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method 
android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from 
method 
android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
02-17 21:31:57.877 1658-1658/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface 
method 15996: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode 
(Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
02-17 21:31:57.877 1658-1658/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 
0x0002
02-17 21:31:57.877 1658-1658/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method 
android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from 
method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
02-17 21:31:57.889 1658-1658/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual 
method 704: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
02-17 21:31:57.889 1658-1658/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 
0x0002
02-17 21:31:57.889 1658-1658/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method 
android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method 
android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
02-17 21:31:57.889 1658-1658/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual 
method 726: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
02-17 21:31:57.889 1658-1658/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 
0x0008
02-17 21:31:57.889 1658-1658/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method 
android.content.Context.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext, referenced from 
method 
android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext
02-17 21:31:57.889 1658-1658/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual 
method 485: Landroid/content/Context;.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext 
()Landroid/content/Context;
02-17 21:31:57.889 1658-1658/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 
0x0006
02-17 21:31:57.889 1658-1658/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method 
android.content.Context.getCodeCacheDir, referenced from method 
android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getCodeCacheDir
02-17 21:31:57.889 1658-1658/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual 
method 491: Landroid/content/Context;.getCodeCacheDir ()Ljava/io/File;
02-17 21:31:57.889 1658-1658/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 
0x0006
02-17 21:31:57.889 1658-1658/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method 
android.content.Context.getColor, referenced from method 
android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getColor
02-17 21:31:57.893 1658-1658/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual 
method 492: Landroid/content/Context;.getColor (I)I
02-17 21:31:57.893 1658-1658/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 
0x0006
02-17 21:31:57.893 1658-1658/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method 
android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method 
android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getColorStateList
02-17 21:31:57.893 1658-1658/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual 
method 493: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList 
(I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
02-17 21:31:57.893 1658-1658/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 
0x0006
02-17 21:31:57.893 1658-1658/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method 
android.content.Context.getDataDir, referenced from method 
android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDataDir
02-17 21:31:57.893 1658-1658/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual 
method 495: Landroid/content/Context;.getDataDir ()Ljava/io/File;
02-17 21:31:57.893 1658-1658/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 
0x0006
02-17 21:31:57.893 1658-1658/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method 
android.content.Context.getDrawable, referenced from method 
android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable
02-17 21:31:57.893 1658-1658/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual 
method 496: Landroid/content/Context;.getDrawable 
(I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
02-17 21:31:57.893 1658-1658/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 
0x0006
```

Comment: Edit your question to include logcat. See: [Unfortunately MyApp Has Stopped How Can I Solve This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: That logcat is unrelated to the exception. Try to find the words `Caused by`

Answer (score -1):

Might be many things, for example: you forgot to add your activity to the manifest.
But I am going to go ahead and guess that you dont have a root layout which should be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:src="@drawable/androidparty" />


<TextView
android:text="Happy Birthday Mohamed"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:textSize="36sp"
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
android:text="From,Abo Elmagd"
android:textSize="36sp"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:id="@+id/textView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry but i didn't Understand What should i do

Comment: Please Anyone Help me :(

Comment: Please don't guess at answers for poor questions. Wait for those how can comment to ask for the right information. Question had bad XML indentation. Root element was there. See update

Comment: it wasnt when I was replying